# Lock GLSurfaceView thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es

I have code for cooperation UI and OpenGL renderer. But I have problem with threads. I need to lock GLSurfaceView thread and execute desire method. How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "locking" the thread.

To execute code on the GLSurfaceView renderer thread from another thread, use [`queueEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#queueEvent(java.lang.Runnable)).

If you can't do what you want with GLSurfaceView, use a plain SurfaceView.  You'll have to do your own EGL setup as well as the thread management, but you can find examples for the tricky bits in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: Thanks, it's really help.